# How to look up value in a list of map?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>>`. Given two keys, how to return the `Long` value using streams?

For example

```
    List<Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> lMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Long> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(10, 100L);
    map1.put(20, 200L);
    lMap1.put(1, map1);
    listOfMap.add(lMap1);

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> lMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Long> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put(30, 300L);
    map2.put(40, 400L);
    lMap2.put(2, map2);
    listOfMap.add(lMap2);
```

Given `1` and `10`, it would return `100`.

Comment: But every map in the list can have same keys, what then?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. Missed the important part.

Comment: If finding first such occurrence works, one can use a function defined with `getOrDefault` as in the following `long val = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        ToLongFunction<Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>> findVal =
                el -> el.getOrDefault(outerKey, Collections.emptyMap())
                        .getOrDefault(innerKey, Long.MIN_VALUE);
        return listOfMap.stream()
                .filter(el -> findVal.applyAsLong(el) != Long.MIN_VALUE)
                .findFirst()
                .map(findVal::applyAsLong)
                .orElse(val);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to look into each Map in List and check for both keys in nested maps, you can do something like below -

```
OptionalLong optional = listOfMap.stream().filter(x -> x.containsKey(1) && x.get(1).containsKey(10)).mapToLong(x -> x.get(1).get(10)).findFirst();
if (optional.isPresent()) {
  return optional.getAsLong();
}
```

Use stream to iterate over list and filter elements containing maps with required values and return first element matching out criteria.

For aggregating, instead of findFirst(), you can reduce by adding starting with 0 as identity.

```
long l = listOfMap.stream().filter(x -> x.containsKey(1) && x.get(1).containsKey(10)).mapToLong(x -> x.get(1).get(10)).reduce(0L, (left, right) -> left + right);
```

Comment: If multiple maps in the list contain the same key, the first map from the list will be picked by the `if`. Are you sure that is what OP wants?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answer from `@DhruvilVaghela` you might want to do the following:

```java
public long getValue(int key1, int key2) {
    long val = listOfMap.stream().filter(
            x -> x.containsKey(key1) && x.get(key1).containsKey(key2)).mapToLong(
                  x -> x.get(key1).get(key2)).findFirst().orElse(Long.MAX_VALUE);

    return val;
}
```

As you would need to return something from the method, this uses the `orElse` feature of the `optional` to provide an alternate answer in case the `key(s)` are not present in the map.

You could also specify a default value in the method signature to return in case the `keys(s)` were not present.